# Ajax redirect broken when not uploading a file

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have a small bug where it would always redirect to a URL when I'm not uploading a file but when I upload a file it works perfectly and JS successfully captures the data for the user from Django.

I tried changing up the function and redirects but unfortunately it's probably not that simple...

Anyhow, here's the code I have written so far:

```
type: 'POST',
headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
url: window.location.href,
data: examData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function (data) {
    if (data.user_groups.includes('rasp') || data.user_groups.includes('canyon')) {
            window.location.href = "{% url 'red' %}";
    } else {
            window.location.href = "{% url 'blue' %}";
    }
}
```

The code above checks in the success Ajax function based on the given data to redirect to either red/ or blue/ depending on whether the user has those groups. As mentioned it works perfectly when the user hasn't uploaded a file.

views.py

```
for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
    handle_uploaded_file(request, f, task=db_item)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Success! Area added.')
    if request.user.groups.filter(name=rasp).exists() or request.user.groups.filter(name=canyon).exists():              
        user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
        data = {'user_groups': user_groups}
    return JsonResponse(data)
else:
    if request.user.groups.filter(name=rasp).exists() or request.user.groups.filter(name=canyon.exists():              
        user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
        data = {'user_groups': user_groups}
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blue'))
```

This is the django function in views.py when a submit is clicked on the client-side and the file is uploaded, afterwards the AJAX redirects based on the user data.

Edit: My goal is to make it check when there's no file uploaded as well, so basically the same functionality but when there's no file uploaded.

Currently it always redirects to blue/ when no file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

to have the same functionality when no file is uploaded you should include the logic for the case when no file is uploaded within your `views.py` file so your `views.py` should looks like this:

```
# change "your_view_function" to the actual name of your view function
def your_view_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.FILES:  # Check if files are uploaded
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                handle_uploaded_file(request, f, task=db_item)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Success! Area added.')
            if request.user.groups.filter(name='rasp').exists() or request.user.groups.filter(name='canyon').exists():
                user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
                data = {'user_groups': user_groups}
                return JsonResponse(data)
            else:
                user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
                data = {'user_groups': user_groups}
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blue'))
        else:
            if request.user.groups.filter(name='rasp').exists() or request.user.groups.filter(name='canyon').exists():
                user_groups = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True))
                data = {'user_groups': user_groups}
                return JsonResponse(data)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blue'))
    else:
        # your logic here for handling GET request goes here
        pass
```

this code checks if there are uploaded files in the request, if there are, it processes then accordingly and redirectsbased on the user's groups if there are no uploaded files it directly checks the user's groups and performs the redirection based on the groups.

I hope this helps you.